# Syncing an Outlook calendar to SharePoint Calendar

Tags: outlook, sync

I connected the SharePoint calendar with my Outlook and copied over the events that I wanted to show up on SharePoint as I saw in a YouTube tutorial. However, I am worried that anything new that I am unaware of will not be synced to the SharePoint calendar. Is there a way to sync two Outlook calendars so they stay in sync with each others events?

Comment: The Outlook calendar can email the SharePoint calendar and be synced. Are you doing that?

Comment: Are you using Exchange or OWA?

Comment: We are using Exchange.